# How to configure Allure on Angular with Jest

Tags: angular, jestjs, allure

I was trying to use Allure on Angular and Jest version 24

I tried to `npm install --save-dev jest-allure`. 
And to put `setupFilesAfterEnv: ["jest-allure/dist/setup"]` on Package.json
When i type

> allure serve

on console there is not found the allure command. 
How can i do it otherwise?. 
Note that i am not familiar with everything on allure.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the `allure serve` command via npm, you must have [allure commandline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/allure-commandline) installed.

Relevant pieces of working configuration for me:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "ng test --noStackTrace",
    "test:ci": "ng test --ci --coverage",
    ...
  },
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ... // tested w/ angular 8
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@angular-builders/jest": "^8.0.4",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.21",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-allure": "^0.1.1",
    ...
  },
  "jest": {
    ...
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "jest-allure/dist/setup"
    ],
  }
}
```